# How to Apply a Cell Style to DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

I have the following `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="cultureDataGrid" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCell}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Cultures, 
                                NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                IsAsync=True}" 
          Style="{x:Null}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language" Binding="{Binding Language}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LocalName" Binding="{Binding LocalName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have the following cell style to change the selected `Backcolor`

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have tried applying the `CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCell}"` as shown above, and using `DynamicResource` but the resource is failing to be resolved. I have imported the correct resource dictionary as other styles are working **What am I doing wrong here?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Assuming that your Style is held in a resource dictionary, wouldn't you need to add a x:Key attribute in order to resolve it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since your `Style` has no `Key` you do not have to set `CellStyle` on the `DataGrid`, it will be applied to all `DataGridCell` by default.

If you dont want it applied to all `DataGridCell` by default give the style an `x:Key` and set the `CellStyle` on the `DataGrid`

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridCell" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCell}" />
```

Comment: Again, utter stupidness by me. I am working after work on my own stuff and I am always knackered. Sorry to waste your time here... One thing that I don't understand is that it was not being applied to the CellStyle by default. Any idea on that as that was why I did not give it a key in the first place? Thanks again...

Comment: If you just use `TargetType` without a `Key` that style will be automaticly applied to all elements of that type unless they have a style declared already using StaticResource/DynamicResource, I just tested DataGrid and its the same If I remove `CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCell}"` from your code the style was applied

Comment: I am going to ask another question based on this answer... I would be very grateful if you could provide some more wisdom.

Comment: That question was again another error on my part - I'm going to bed... Thanks again, it is most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To apply the style to only some DataGridRow :

Create your DataGridCell style :

```
< !-- DataGridCell Style-->
< Style x:Key="MyDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Use it in the column you want

```
< !-- DataGrid -->
<DataGrid >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```