# WPF cell style based on original binding value

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with several columns. Each column contains a differently formatted number. Now I need to apply a style to each cell which is quite the same for most of the columns, but I don't know how to create the common style. The simplified version of the code is this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding Value1, StringFormat='{}{0:N2} eq'}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value1}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Error}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding Value2, StringFormat='{}{0:N0} fon'}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Error}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding Value3, StringFormat='{}0x{0:X4}'}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value3}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Error}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For a different cases (several different TextBlocks) I have successfully used the scenarion that for Text property I use a binding with StringFormat and for styling purposes I also bind the same value to the Tag property which can be then used in the style for the DataTrigger checking. But I don't know how to bind directly to Tag property of the Cell.

I would like to have something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}" Value="0">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Error}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" CellTag_Binding="{Binding Value1}" Binding="{Binding Value1, StringFormat='{}{0:N2} eq'}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" CellTag_Binding="{Binding Value2}" Binding="{Binding Value2, StringFormat='{}{0:N0} fon'}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" CellTag_Binding="{Binding Value3}" Binding="{Binding Value3, StringFormat='{}0x{0:X4}'}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or even something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Original_Value}" Value="0">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Error}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding Value1, StringFormat='{}{0:N2} eq'}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding Value2, StringFormat='{}{0:N0} fon'}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding Value3, StringFormat='{}0x{0:X4}'}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not [create a different style for each column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623810/424129)?

Comment: There is about 20 columns, so creating 20 same styles is quite annoying. Not telling that when I want to change something, I have to change that in 20 styles and not only one.

Comment: You can base them all on a single style that has the common stuff in it.

Comment: Can you post an example? I don't think that it will differ from the first code that I've sent. The main issue is the DataTrigger - that is the core of my problem. The DataTrigger is doing the exactly the same thing for each column and I need to find a way how to generalize it.